# Repeat domain name after domain url?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

How can i write htaccess for codeigniter project below is my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.generaltechuae\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://generaltechuae.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

my domain address is http://www.generaltechuae.com/, 
I can't access inner pages by http://www.generaltechuae.com/index.php/aboutus.
But i can access the about us page by http://www.generaltechuae.com/generaltechuae/index.php/aboutus

and also enclosed my config parameters

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

why generaltechuae is repeat after the domain address

Can someone help me how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**First solution**
It is because you have uploaded all the websites files in your folder name: **"generaltechuae"** .
Currently, your website has base URL:
**http://www.generaltechuae.com/generaltechuae/**
 You have to place all your files in root folder {public_html} to your server.After it your website base url will be:
**http://www.generaltechuae.com/**
So your problem will be resolved.

**Second Solution**
You can have another solution as you can right an  .httpaccess rule, which will ignore your folder name.